# Spring MVC : Tying session attributes to each browser tab

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

- I am working on Spring-MVC application in which I am setting and
  getting some session attributes which I need in backend. The problem
  is, Spring or the browser, someone out of the both is tying these
  session attributes to different browsers rather than different tabs.

  - So if I open a new tab in the same browser, then it is updating the
    session attribute for both tabs.
    How can I remedy this problem? I tried using session to scope, request, etc. But nothing works. here is my controller and servlet-context.xml

Controller :

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class PersonController {


    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadsection/{id}")
    public String loadNotePage(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, HttpSession session) {
// here i am setting the canvasid, which I would like to access in other methods
        session.setAttribute("canvasid",id);
        if (this.personService.returnCurrentOperationalMode()) {

            session.setAttribute("canvasid",id);
            return "redirect:/section/listing";
        } else {
            GroupCanvas mcanvas = this.groupCanvasService.getCanvasById(id);
            this.personService.setCurrentCanvas(mcanvas.getMcanvasid());

            return "redirect:/section/listing";
        }

    }


    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addbatchsections", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addBatchSections(HttpSession session, @RequestBody Section[] sections) {
        int canvasid = (Integer) session.getAttribute("canvasid");
        try {
            List<Section> sectionList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Section section : sections) {
                sectionList.add(section);
            }
            this.sectionService.addBatchSections(sectionList,canvasid);
            return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "failure";
        }
    }
```

Servlet-Context.xml

```
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"  />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Person2"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="asayhk2787" />
        <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"  />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Notes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Canvas</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Section</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Attachment</beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupAccount</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupMembers</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupCanvas</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupSection</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNotes</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupAttachments</beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Token</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.WaitingMembers</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.NoteHistory</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.GroupNoteHistory</beans:value>

                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Feedback</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="connection.pool_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.max_size">200</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="c3p0.timeout">1000</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</beans:prop>

            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

I hope my question was clear, if there is any doubt, please feel free to ask me. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Perhaps the following thread could be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757128/spring-mvc-sessionattributes-issue-in-multiple-browser-tabs/26758402#26758402

Comment: @MasterSlave : My problem is the values I am saving are the same, and the thread doesn't explain how it is doing whatever it is doing.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @jgr : Yes, but we changed our architecture. Spring-security has a way, to define each tab a session. You can check out some docs.

Comment: If you found a solution to your question it would be good to put the exact approach and preferably some up here for the benefit of myself and others

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) and its associated examples.

Comment: Cool. I am checking it out. Any solution incase you know how to give difference canvasId for different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers like Chrome on new tab or new window share the user session because use the same session cookies.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065750/spring-security-how-to-disable-same-session-sharing-across-multiple-tabs-of-sa) or change your session approach.

Comment: Thanks, I already found that HTML5 SessionStorage can be used. I am just searching how to use it in Java to set the canvasId attribute mentioned in the main post and retrieve it in the Controller. If you know how, kindly let me know.

Comment: So you need to share the same canvasId across different web sessions?

Comment: Exactly the opposite, Each browser tab has its own canvasid.

Comment: As I wrote in the response you need an approach to "disable" the browser session sharing, try the one suggested by @manish, you need to bind different session to each tabs so every tab will need to log in.

Comment: Is there any other way where I can maintain the user logged in, but can also get the updated canvasid which is set in each tab by the user himself. That is what I am more interested in.